# File constantly is used by my code and cannot be deleted manually or with code

Tags: vb.net, upload, filestream, delete-file

I am trying to make a voice recognition thing with google's voice api.

I modified UPLOADFILEEX function that can be found on codeproject...

The file I wish to delete is C:\record.flac

Here is the function below

```
         Public Shared Function UploadFile(ByVal uploadfilename As String, ByVal url As String, ByVal fileFormName As String, ByVal contenttype As String, ByVal querystring As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, ByVal cookies As CookieContainer) As String
    If (fileFormName Is Nothing) OrElse (fileFormName.Length = 0) Then
        fileFormName = "file"
    End If
    If (contenttype Is Nothing) OrElse (contenttype.Length = 0) Then
        contenttype = "application/octet-stream"
    End If
    Dim postdata As String
    postdata = "?"
    If Not (querystring Is Nothing) Then
        For Each key As String In querystring.Keys
            postdata += key + "=" + querystring.Get(key) + "&"
        Next
    End If
    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(url + postdata)
    Dim boundary As String = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
    Dim webrequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
    webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies
    webrequest.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=16000"
    webrequest.Method = "POST"
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    sb.Append("--")
    sb.Append(boundary)
    sb.Append("" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "")
    sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""")
    sb.Append(fileFormName)
    sb.Append("""; filename=""")
    sb.Append(IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadfilename))
    sb.Append("""")
    sb.Append("" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "")
    sb.Append("Content-Type: ")
    sb.Append(contenttype)
    sb.Append("" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "")
    sb.Append("" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "")
    Dim postHeader As String = sb.ToString
    Dim postHeaderBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader)
    Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "--" + boundary + "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(13) & "" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(10) & "")
    Dim fileStreama As FileStream = New FileStream(uploadfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim length As Long = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStreama.Length + boundaryBytes.Length
    webrequest.ContentLength = length
    Dim requestStream As Stream = webrequest.GetRequestStream
    requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length)
    Dim sendBuffer(Math.Min(4096, fileStreama.Length)) As Byte
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
    Do
        bytesRead = fileStreama.Read(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length)
        If bytesRead = 0 Then Exit Do
        requestStream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
    Loop
    requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)
    Dim responce As WebResponse = webrequest.GetResponse
    Dim s As Stream = responce.GetResponseStream
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s)
    Return sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Dispose()
    s.Dispose()
    fileStreama.Dispose()
    requestStream.Dispose()
    webrequest.Abort()
    responce.Close()

End Function
```

The function WORKS (Thankgod) but whenever I want to clear up (i.e. delete the audio file that is located in the c:) it just hangs and nothing happens...

Below is my code that executes on the formclosing event....

```
      Private Sub Form1_Close(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
    For Each dra In diar1
        If dra.Name.Contains("record.") Then
            dra.Delete()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As you probably may be able to see from the function I HAVE TRIED TO REMOVE ALL THE STREAMS AND CLOSE THEM SO THE FILE IS NOT BEING ACCESSED

BUT it still hangs and when I try manually delete it... it tells me it is being used by another process (which is my program) - (I use ffmpeg to convert the .wav to .flac file but that does not cause any problems)....

What am I doing wrong...

Have I missed the closing of some stream or something.

By the way the uploadfilename string is c:\record.flac (just for your information - I dont think it will help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is calling `Return` BEFORE disposing of the file stream.  This means that your Dispose call is never fired.. and the stream holds onto a file reference.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I can't believe I didn't think of that before!

Comment: @ImranAhmed - I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler warning about unreachable code!  Is Option Strict On?

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Boo that the return before the dispose probably is the cause. So the solution would be to store the result of sr.ReadToEnd in a variable, close the streams and then return the var.

But a better solution would be to use the Using statement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) on every class that you have to call .Dispose() on (aka classes that implement IDisposable).

This gives clearer code because you can easily see what resources are in use where in your code. Also less buggy code as .NET ensures that everything is disposed once you leave the scope of the using block.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment (How do I answer this question as "answered"?)

Comment: I think there should be a large checkmark next to each answer which you can click.